# Multiple data sources in XPages

Tags: xpages

I have 2 xpages that interact together.   The first acts as a homepage and allows the user to create a new document and fill out some basic header information.   The button to create the new document, sets a `sessionScope` var with the `NoteID`.  It then saves document1 and opens the same document using another xpage.

The second xpages is bound to document1, and uses the `sessionScope` to edit the document.  This xpages contains and editPanel bound to document2.   I want to create a child document to document2.   This works but what happens is document1 is also saved as conflict.  It is also saved as a second main document.

I DO NOT want to save document1 at all, but can't seem to prevent it.  The button that creates document2 uses the simple action save document, and specfies document2.

HELP, I have tried everything, and have been stuck on this for 2 days.

Thanks!
Steve

Answer (score 2):

To bind to multiple datasources, on your XPage, under Properties expand Data and set "Ignore Request Params" to TRUE

Comment: I was using this parameter but it still failed.  This helped it work, but the backend was still messed up.  Thanks for answering!!

Answer (score 1):

If you change the type of your buttons, to a simple button instead of a submit button, and handle the `doc.save()` yourself should solve your problem.

Comment: So far, this seemed to fix my issue.  Thanks Gabriel!

Answer (score 1):

The Save Document simple action accepts the name of the data source to save as a String argument. If supplied, it will only save that specific data source.